# how get user idle time using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to get the user idle time using jQuery I use jQuery but it works only current tab means (document.body) but actually I want user are in any working or not notepad, excel, gmail anything I use the the code below:

```
var idleTime = 0; var min = -1;
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Increment the idle time counter every minute.
    var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 1000); // 1 min

    //Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
    $(this).mousemove(function (e) {
        idleTime = 0; min = -1;
    });
    $(this).keypress(function (e) {
        idleTime = 0; min = -1;
    });
});
function timerIncrement() {

    if (idleTime%60==0)
    { min = min + 1; }
    $("#idea").html(min+":"+idleTime);
    idleTime = idleTime + 1;
    if (idleTime > 10) { // 10 minutes
    alert("i miss you :-)");
    }
}
```

but it is not work it gives only current tab idle time but i want whole system idle time using my website by jQuery it is possible or not i use this code in c# but window form...pls help me in jQuery web.

Comment: For security reasons, you can't do this: The browser won't report what the user is doing outside it, or even in another tab.

Comment: but i am working on c# mvc4.  In c# or vb script are possible this work .dll file can access user system idle time outside of browser.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you're running on the server. Code it in C# or Python or Ruby or JavaScript under Node, and it still doesn't matter, because you want to know idle time on the _client_, through the _browser_, and that is prohibited information. The browser does not allow you access to information outside its sandbox on the client, period, no matter what you might be able to do on the server.

Comment: thank you sir, but i need client idle time it is possible if i m using.exe file in window form it is possible or nor get system idle time..

Comment: If you're loading the web page inside a WebBrowser control inside a custom application that you wrote in Windows Forms (or equivalent), then the Windows Forms application _can_ obtain that information (with effort), and inject it into the web content (also with effort).  But if you're loading the web page inside a normal web browser (Chrome, Firefox, IE, Edge, Safari), it's impossible (for security reasons) to access that data.  (Note, however, that in IE, this can be overcome with an ActiveX control in some cases, but ActiveX is a dead technology and should not be used in new software.)